# GWT refresh CssResource class when style.css is modified with Eclipse

Tags: java, css, eclipse, gwt, cssresource

I'm using a CssResource class for my GWT app styles and I'm trying to find a way to trigger the refresh my java interface when my style.css file is modified (or the other way around, to refresh my style.css when the java interface is modified).

I'm developing in Eclipse and I know that the java interface can be created with the ClientBundle wizard, but is there a way to refresh one of them, when the other one is modified so I won't write the same strings twice ?

Comment: In IntelliJ, if you refactor the name of a method in CssResource, it automatically updates the corresponding lines in the css. Can you test if it also works in Eclipse? (Shortcut : Alt + Shift + R)

Comment: It doesn't refactor the .css file. The auto update is more useful when adding styles, so event if it would work, i don't think it will help my big issue :)